# D3 Date Parse Using Time Format

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3.js. I have a date string like "01 DEC 2017". I need to fetch year from it. I am using time format. It's returning null. What is wrong in my code ? Advance thanks for any help.

My code :

d.date = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse("01 DEC 2017").getFullYear();

Comment: It should be `d.date = d3.time.format("%d %b %Y").parse("01 DEC 2017").getFullYear()`

Comment: **Edit:** D3 V4 version: var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d %b %Y"). Docs here: https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format

Comment: @REEE OP is using v3. She's doing it right, only the specifier is wrong.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Oh yeah, sorry. I had to check the docs to find the right params for her date string, didn't realise I had copy and pasted the updated version. I'll edit that in to my comment now, thanks. When I said the *right* way I was referring to the params I didn't even realise I had copied over the wrong syntax.

Comment: No. Sorry. Still it's not working. Same Output. Null. I am using version 3.5.3 @GerardoFurtado

Comment: @Rachita It is working: https://jsfiddle.net/uvyeftLj/

Comment: Thank you for your help. But for some reason I am not getting the output . So, I using direct JS to fetch year.